# Fancybox - Clicking a link on iframe, updates URL address

Tags: jquery, url, iframe, fancybox, fancybox-2

Right now I have an iFrame content being open with fancybox. When it opens, it updates the URL address to match the iFrame URL. When it closes, it'll return to the previous URL. The problem is that inside the iFrame I have navigation keys to go between posts. Doing so won't update the URL address like if it was closed and opened. Is there any way I can achieve this?

The code is:

**JS**

```
$(".caption a").fancybox({
    type: 'iframe',
    width    : '1470px', 
    height   : '1800px', 
    transitionIn : 'fade',
    transitionOut : 'fade',
    autoScale: false,
    autoDimensions: false,
    autoSize    : false, 
    arrows    : false,
    nextClick : false,
    padding : 0,
    beforeShow: function () {
        $.cookie('window_location', window.location, { path: '/' }); 
        window.history.pushState("string", "Title", $(this).attr('href'));  
    },
    afterClose: function() {
        window.history.pushState("string", "Title", $.cookie('window_location'));   
        $.removeCookie('window_location', { path: '/' });
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="caption">            
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

I've created a working example of what is going on right now. http://josemelo.net/testing/

As you can see, when you click to open the iframe, it'll update the browser's URL with the page you're iframing, in this case iframe.html. However, if you navigate to page2 inside the iframe, the URL won't update. I want it to update! So basically the goal here is that whenever you navigate to other pages inside iframe, it'll keep updating the URL.

Inside http://josemelo.net/testing/ I have a file named index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="fancybox-2.1.5.js"></script>
    <script src="cookie-1.4.0.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            type: 'iframe',
            width    : '800px', 
            height   : '600px', 
            transitionIn : 'fade',
            transitionOut : 'fade',
            autoScale: false,
            autoDimensions: false,
            autoSize    : false, 
            arrows    : false,
            nextClick : false,
            padding : 0,
            helpers: { overlay: { locked: false } },
            beforeShow: function () {
                $.cookie('window_location', window.location, { path: '/' }); 
                window.history.pushState("string", "Title", $(this).attr('href'));  
            },
            afterClose: function() {
                window.history.pushState("string", "Title", $.cookie('window_location'));   
                $.removeCookie('window_location', { path: '/' });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="iframe.html" class="fancybox">Click to open iframe</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Another named iframe.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="page2.html">Click to go to page 2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Another named page2.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    This is page 2! Wanna go back? <a href="iframe.html">Click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And links to fancybox js and css and jQuery's cookie js. You can download the whole package in http://josemelo.net/testing/testing.zip

Comment: I read 3 times your question and I am not too sure what you are asking? does the iframe content belong to the same domain as the opening page?

Comment: Yes. Thing is, imagine you're opening a fancybox iframe. Inside the iframe you'll navigate through pages (within the same domain) and the URL will change to those specific pages addresses even though you're viewing the pages in fancybox. Do you understand? In my code above everytime you open fancybox it'll change the URL address to the one of the page, even though you're viewing it through fancybox. I want the same but when changing pages inside the iframe itself.

Comment: Sorry but not. The URL of the iframe never changes despite you navigate to other pages inside the iframe http://jsfiddle.net/hy9qe8hp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everyone comes across this question, I've found a way to go around this and make it work. Basically all you need to do on each iframe page (or in this case the first one), is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $("document").ready(function() {
        $("a.lala").click(function() {
            var cenas = $(this).attr('href');
            window.top.history.pushState("string", "Title", cenas);
        });
    });
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <a href="page2.html" class="lala">Click to go to page 2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This will basically update the parent's URL to the value in the link's `href`.

`$("a.lala").click(function() {`
When a user clicks the link below, with the "lala" class.

`var cenas = $(this).attr('href');` creating a var named "cenas" to retrieve the content in the link's `href=""`

`window.top.history.pushState("string", "Title", cenas);` update parent's URL with the var "cenas", which is the href.

Cheers everyone.